# Programmatically inserting a new user into an aspnet membership schema

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, asp.net-membership

I have a custom implementation of an aspnet membership, called MyWSAT (`mywsat.codeplex.com`).  This implementation simply adds some functionality to the existing aspnet membership.  So, I need a way to programmatically insert new users into the aspnet_membership tables.  MyWSAT comes with a GUI front end to add users, and is web based.  So, I ran SQL profiler as I was inserting a user via the front end.  I have all the information I need to do this, but the question I have is:

**QUESTION**: SQL Profiler shows an encrypted password variable and a salt variable being passed into one of the stored procedures.  Obviously, if I want to automatically insert new users, my code will need the clear text password so that I can email the credentials to the user.  During new user creation, is there a way to say, hey, I'm going to give this user a password of ABC123, via my code, but when calling the stored procedures, generate the encrypted equivalent and salt for that password to pass in to the stored procedure that saves the data to the database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't used MYWSAT yet but if it works with the default ASP.Net membership provider then try this:

```
MembershipUser newUser = Membership.CreateUser("username", "password", "email@a.com");
```

The membership provider will determine whether to encrypt or send a clear password. It really depends on your settings in your web.config (system.web --> membership --> providers).

Comment: Yep, easy as that.  Thanks.  Works.